# Make a CodeIgniter app use MySQL replication the right way

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-replication

I have a really nasty problem with a CodeIgniter application which I want to load balance using also MySQL replication.

In other PHP frameworks this would be a 5minute job because you may switch the datasource just before saving the data (CakePHP allows this, for example), but it seems in CodeIgniter that's a different story.
My problem is the application is legacy and I have to load balance it so I have all the hardware setup already done, the filesystem is in sync, the database has a slave and updates it as it should, but I have to make the second CodeIgniter application to read from the slave and write to the master.

I already found a solution but since the application is legacy I wouldn't want to go into its internals because I could destroy something that already works (it's also pretty sensible because people are paying within the app and it's also live which makes things even worse).

The solution I've found is [this one](http://labs.earthpeople.se/2011/08/codeigniter-activerecord-setup-to-use-master-slave-db-replication/) which makes you change all the models in the application. 
As further information CodeIgniter database driver (**CI_DB_mysql_driver** in this case) doesn't have any method for switching the connection or something.

**Do you have another suggestion for tackling this problem?** (besides changing all the models which I find a bit too intrusive)

Comment: The only thing I can think will make refactoring easier (well, less urgent) is to use a wrapper object, that contains both the master and slave connections, that switches connections, based on what method is being called (read operations use slave, writes use master). and implement a `__call` method to catch any omissions. After that has been implemented, you can actually set about changing the model layer to cope with replications, because a wrapper will just be extra overhead

Comment: Oh: is adding a parent to the models an option? It needn't be the only parent, nor need it be an astract, but you could just have them all extend from  a class that _does_ enable switching connections?

Comment: Yeah, I could do that but I'd have to filter the calls to $this->db. Maybe there's also the possibility to use the database in the controller without loading the model? I guess if that's possible it would make things a bit more complicated

Comment: Well, if you want to use it in the controller, then you're using your controllers for something they _shouldn't be used_, and you're back to writing a wrapper. That said: The _Model_ in MVC isn't a single object, but a layer, so you could just as well introduce a DB service to the model layer, and centralize DB operations there. It'll make life easier if ever you were to change DB's, too

Comment: I know you shouldn't use the database in the controller, but unfortunately I didn't write the app and it's too big to rewrite the right way. I guess the easiest way to cover it all in this situation means that I have to make a database driver and handle all the slave logic there to also catch the improper usage of the database in the controllers. Thanks!

Comment: No need to thank me, I'm sorry I can't point you towards some magical sollution. The only thing you can do, I'm afraid is to implement an exception handler that catches write operations that failed (because they were attempted on the slave), and tries to run them on the master. But that's just hacky and dead-slow... but it's the fix requiring the least work